# elasticsearch disk space by field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster that indexes twitter data in a different index based on the day of the tweet.

The disk space used for 4 million tweets was about 5GB.

After making some changes to the fields that are stored and enriching the data with additional information a new index of 2 million documents uses about 8GB.

The mappings for both the old and new are identical, The only difference is the old index wont have data in some of the fields.

I expected an increase in storage space usage but this is excessive. I have a theory that the bounding box field may be the one using most of this space.

I have looked at the API's and cant see one that will show the amount of disk space used by an individual field. Is there any way to get this information so I can compare the two indexes?

I'm not interested in fielddata size. I need to know the space used on disk for the terms index for an individual field.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution, but you can create a copy of the index with only few fields you want the size.

This should give you a good number.

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter",
    "_source": ["user", "_doc"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  }
}
```